# Why am I getting ArgumentError: invalid %-encoding?

Tags: ruby, ramaze

This code fetches the content in plain text or html, and displays it on the page.

A HTML form with the fields `post_id` `content` POSTS to `edit_post` in my controller. I'm using [Sequel ORM](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) and [Ramaze](http://ramaze.net).

```
def edit_post
  Encoding.default_external = 'utf-8'
  data = request.subset(:content, :post_id)
  shake = Post[data['post_id']]
  data.delete('post_id'); 
  shake.update(data); shake.save
end
```

The only symbols inside data['content'] is `%` `,` `.` `'` and `"`

The desired behaviour is that the POST data submitted through the form updates the row in the database. [This is the string](https://gist.github.com/desbest/b1add0ccee6cf7eb2128) I was trying to post. It contains this line that includes 2 percent signs (`%`):

```
A scientific study showed that men want more sex partners than women, in every country. Only 2% of lesbians have had over 1000 sexual partners, but 28% of gays have had over 1000.
```

The table row requires a "content" and "post_id" column.

It looks like there's a problem with the `%` symbol being used to update the database. I believe the default encoding to be CP850. How do I change my Ramaze app to stop using CP850 and use UTF-8 instead?

I have the following code in `model/init.rb`

```
Sequel::Model.plugin :force_encoding, 'UTF-8'
Encoding.default_external = 'utf-8'
```

[Here is a stack trace.](https://gist.github.com/desbest/9a6c24b7e03cf8d50e44)

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("*why isn't this code working?*") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Questions without *a clear problem statement* are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've updated my question. Is it fine now?

Comment: Your question is much better now, thanks! What would make it perfect would be a stacktrace of exception which allows us to better spot what went wrong.

Comment: Here's a stacktrace. https://gist.github.com/desbest/9a6c24b7e03cf8d50e44